# Google App Engine auth for Google APIs using service account

Tags: python, google-app-engine, calendar, google-oauth

**TL;DR  What is the preferred way of doing this now that service accounts need domain-wide delegation set up?**

I have a GAE project (python 2.7 runtime) that uses the Google Calendar API v3. Up until last week, I had been using the default GAE service account to connect to the calendar API, and the service account was given read/write permission to the calendar under calendar sharing settings.

Since last Thursday Oct 20, the service account cannot write to the calendar (events.post or events.patch) -- returns a 403 Forbidden -- and reads (events.list) return 200, but no records. Checking the permissions for the account under calendar sharing, it has been changed to "See Free/Busy only".

I believe this is related to this announcement from Google about winding down OAuth 1.0 service accounts on Oct 20:  https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/saying-goodbye-to-oauth-10-2lo.html

The recommendation seems to be to grant Domain Wide Delegation to the service account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority  However, the GAE default service account does not list a `client_id`. So we set up a new service account, and granted it Domain-Wide Delegation.

But the new service account doesn't work any better. I tried using both `AppAssertionCredentials`, and created a JSON key file and tried using `ServiceAccountCredentials`, as detailed on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

`AppAssertionCredentials` doesn't seem to work because the account is not the default service account, even passing in a `service_account_id` param.

`ServiceAccountCredentials` does refresh the key etc. but I get the same behavior as with the default service account:  403 Forbidden errors on writes and no records returned on reads.

I have double-checked the new service account has domain-wide delegation set up and under the calendar permissions it is listed as "Make changes to events".

**EDIT**:

We also were able to set domain-wide delegation for the default GAE service account. However, it still does not work using either `AppAssertionCredentials` or `ServiceAccountCredentials`. I get the same behavior:  403 Forbidden errors on writes and no records returned on reads.

**EDIT #2**:

We also tried setting up a new service account from scratch, setting DwD, and permissions for the account on the calendar. Same behavior, and the calendar permissions are forced to "See only free/busy", with the other options greyed out.